# How to prevent sending requests with token for others

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Web API project. I'm using JWT Token and it have user mail in it. I noticed something, If someone have token after login can send request for other user.

I have a few endpoints like that

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string userMail)
    {
        return Ok(await _writeService.RenameAndSaveFile(Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault(), userMail));
    }
```

How do i avoid sending requests for others?

Comment: don't take userMail as parameter but take it from the claims of the current user. User should be set on your controller, assuming all middleware is wired correctly.

Comment: @rene thanks for comment. You mean `var test = User.Identity.Name;` like this in endpoints and what you mean all middleware is wire correctly?

Comment: The token is used to identity which user send the request,  so it's impossible to prevent user send token for other. One possible way is you could just allow token to use just once.

Comment: @BrandoZhang ım sending token to client and client storage in local storage. When I take the token and use it with postman then I can send request how can ı prevent it? should i get it like this instead of parameter `var test = User.Identity.Name;`

Comment: The thing is the token contain the claims which contain the username or ID normally. No matter who get the token, if the request contains that token, this will be regarded as that user send.  So What's your actually requirement? Just allow specific user get the token or allow specific user send the request?

Comment: @BrandoZhang as I said if I have any my backend token ı can send request for other users with email parameter. I want to do this like as you said.  I shouldn't get user email via parameter of endpoint  and I want to know what is the best way